# Adding items to activity toolbar and removing them when I leave the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I am trying to do the following:
I got several fragments and there is one where should be an edit and a delete icon displayed in the activity's toolbar. When I quit this fragment they should be removed. The problem is.. I do not know the problem actually, that's why I ask for. Here is my fragment (Also I would like you to watch my code and tell me what I could improve and change there because I think it is pretty messy):

```
public class ContentFragment extends Fragment {


    public ContentFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    TextView title;
    TextView content;
    TextView username;
    TextView date;
    TextView plus;
    TextView minus;

    String titlev;
    String contentv;
    String authorv;
    String datev;
    String usernamev;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        RelativeLayout lv = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_content, container, false);
        title = (TextView) lv.findViewById(R.id.titlein);
        content = (TextView) lv.findViewById(R.id.contentin);
        username = (TextView) lv.findViewById(R.id.usernamein);
        date = (TextView) lv.findViewById(R.id.datein);

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        titlev = preferences.getString("title", "");
        contentv = preferences.getString("content", "");
        authorv = preferences.getString("author", "");
        datev = preferences.getString("date", "");
        usernamev = preferences.getString("usernames", "");

        System.out.println("CF: " + titlev + contentv + authorv + datev);

        title.setText(titlev);
        content.setText(contentv);
        username.setText(authorv);
        date.setText(datev);

        //GET THE ACTIVITY TOOLBAR
        Toolbar toolbar2 = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar2.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_author);
        toolbar2.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_delete) {
                    System.out.println("DELETE2_______");
                } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_edit) {
                    System.out.println("EDIT2________");
                }
                return true;
            }

        });

        return lv;
    } }
```

menu_author is the xml which SHOULD be applied always when the fragment is called and menu_ is the xml which is used for the activity in common.

I tried the following:

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        System.out.println("HIDDEN");
        Toolbar toolbar2 = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar2.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        System.out.println("SHOWED");
        Toolbar toolbar2 = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar2.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_author);
        super.onResume();
    }
```

But it did not work, so what should I use?

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Just use (toolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_item_id).setVisible(false);) to hide an icon  and (.setVisible(true)) to show it

Comment: Thank you that helped!!
But now I also got the overflow action and whenever I change the visibility of the menu icons the overflow action gets one option more, for example:
Changed visibility twice:
"About this app" "About this app" when I click on, changed four times its like four times this text. Why is that?

Comment: try doing the same then for the overflow item (toolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_item_id).setVisible(fa‌​lse);) Without looking at the new code for your app  im not sure why it adds one more item in the overflow menu when you show an item again.

Comment: Done and fixed! Thank you very much!